# Define a variable and add 1 to it's value

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core, calculations

I'm programming a calendar in `LaTeX` and as it should be used for my univertsity planning, I want to split it up in semesters. So on one page there are the months from September to February and on the second page, there will be the months March to August.

To have a dynamic code which I don't have to touch after finishing the calandar, I'm defining all the variables that will be used in the preamble.

For example

```
\def\year{2017}
```

This variable is later called by the Tikz calendar. My problem is, that the version of the calendar spreads over two different years. My idea was to define a second variable `\def\nextyear` which is equal to `\year + 1`. Unfortunately `\def\nextyear{\year+1}` returns `2017+1` instead of `2018`...

How can I add one year to my variable?

Comment: You need `\numexpr` to carry out the [integer] calculation and `\the` to display the result as text. So try `\edef\nextyear{\the\numexpr\year+1\relax}` maybe?

Comment: Great! This works perfectly.

Comment: Just remember, `\edef` will evaluate `\nextyear` at the time of `\edef` invocation, whereas if you use `\def`, it will be evaluated at the time of `\nextyear` invocation.

Comment: It's a bad idea to do `\def\year{2017}`, as `\year` is a predefined count register (holding the current year).

Comment: @egreg Could you please tell my why that's a bad idea?

Comment: @Sam Because you're destroying an internal variable of TeX. Just use a different name for your variable. And, with LaTeX, *always* use `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` makes the trick.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \def \currentYear {2016}
  \def \n {4}
  \foreach \i in {0,...,\n}
  {

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextYear}{\currentYear + \i}
  \node (N) at (\i,\i) {\nextYear};
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]